# regex replace href value between " and " for <a> not <link> tags

Tags: regex

Using Sublime Text 2, I want to use regex to replace every href value between " and " with a new value.

Example:

```
<a href="link/to/somewhere.html">
```

convert to

```
<a href="#">
```

But the href has to have a corresponding `<a>` tag not within a `<link>` tag.

Comment: How does this work for you? `<a (?:.+ )?href="([^"]+)"(?:[^>]+)?>`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - that seems to select the entire anchor

Comment: @hwnd - link tags have hrefs (links to css files). So I only want to target href's for replacement within anchor tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*

```
Find: (<a[^>]*href=")[^"]*("[^>]*>)
Replace: $1#$2
```

Alternatively, you can use the `\K` escape sequence which is little more simpler. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
Find: <a[^>]*href="\K[^"]*
Replace: #
```

Comment: perfect. thank you. I was stuck on the anchor reference.

Comment: I tried `<link[^>]*href="\K[^"]*` and it is working fine but then I tried `<script[^>]*href="\K[^"]*` and it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In Sublime Text 2:

```
Find What:    <a (.+ )?href="([^"]+)"([^>]+)?>
Replace With: <a \1href="#"\3>
```